# How to call a method onload in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, methods, static-methods, domcontentloaded

So I want to call a function Local.getThis onload with this code:

```
    class Local {
        getThis() {
            let that;
            if (localStorage.getItem('that') === null) {
                that = [];
                console.log(that);
                localStorage.setItem('that', that);
            } else {
                that=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('that'));
                console.log(that);
            }
        }

    // DOM Load Event 
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', Local.getThis)
```

But nothing is happening, no error nothing. But when I change "getThis" to STATIC it works (Output: []). Does it need to be STATIC ??

**P.S.**

After setting that = []; I get an error

```
'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDocument.getThis'
```

on the next reload but that is probably a whole other problem I guess.

**EDIT:**

For the record the error was related to `localStorage.setItem('that', that);`, it should be ofcourse `localStorage.setItem('that', JSON.stringify(that));`

Comment: I believe you'd need to create a new instance of the class before using one of its instance methods. I.e., `new Local()` before trying to use `getThis`

Answer (score 2):

part 1: **this** is a reserved word in JavaScript, change parameter's name.

part 2: Local is a class, so to access a function directly from it that function must be static. Otherwise an instance needs to be initiated first. and the function can then be used from that instance.

Comment: Sorry for this mistake but it is actually a part of a more complex program so i named it 'this' just for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an instance of Local class first to have `this`

```
const local = new Local();
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', local.getThis.bind(local))
//or
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  local.getThis();
})
```

**Update**

Also you cannot use variable name `this` as it is reserved word.
If you don't need a context (`this`) you can create a method as a static method:

```
class Local{}
Local.getThis = function() {
 // code without this
}
```

so then you can use as you've written:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', local.getThis);
```

Answer (score 1):

> But nothing is happening, no error nothing. But when I change
>   "getThis" to STATIC it works (Output: []). Does it need to be STATIC
>   ??

To call your method as **Local.getThis** need to be **static**.

**Otherwise** you need to **create an instance** of Local.

```
var local = new Local();
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  local.getThis();
})
```